# Handle different source folder in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, testing, integration-testing

The Project I am working on has the regular src/main and src/test folders, but they recently introduced src/integration-test, which is supposed to contain, as the name suggests, integration-tests.

Unfortunately I can't seem to make this work with Maven and Eclipse. I tried adding a source folder, but Eclipse is not able to resolve the dependencies needed for the integration-tests and fails to compile the test-classes. I also can't start the tests with JUnit.

The source folder was added to the build path, but it did not help.

All other developers in my team use IntelliJ and report that they don't have these issues at all. But it´s bound to work with Eclipse as well, right?

Comment: yes should work in eclipse to when you add the folder as type source-folder.

Comment: That´s what I tried, but Eclipse can't resolve the test imports.

Comment: Usually, you don't do this, but put _both_ unit and integration tests into the test folder. Then you separate them by naming conventions.

Answer (score 0):

You should handle this with maven by adding the source folder to the build:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>add-test-source</id>
                    <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>add-test-source</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <sources>
                            <source>src/integration</source>
                        </sources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

In this example the build will add a `src/integration` folder where you can put other test classes.

For more information check the [build helper plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/usage.html) documentation.

Comment: Thank you! That did it.